# The reason for changable MAC address

Tags: mac-address

To my understanding, the mac address is supposed to be hard wired on the network card. It is also the so called physical address, and it should be unique. But it is allowed to be modified by the OS, say Window 10. So, is it really communicate with other machine by the new MAC address? Or is the old MAC address still existing on a mapping table somewhere? Is there any rule for creating the custom MAC address? Also, if it is changeable, then it is not unique anymore. What is the point for a hard wired MAC address if it is changeable?

Thanks

Comment: One use for this ability is to give a backup network interface on a server the same MAC as the main interface.  If the main interface fails for any reason, you can just move the cable over to the backup port, and all clients will be able to continue talking to the server - they might otherwise have to wait until the original MAC expired from routing tables.

Answer (score 1):

### What is a Mac Address?

The real Mac address of the network card is unique and immutable.
the Mac address is used on the local network to route the packets :

- the router/pc will say : "who has 192.168.1.4?"
- The pc with this ip will answer "192.168.1.4 has  DC:23:F5:B5:FF:31:94"
- The PC/Router will send the packet via ARP protocol to the specified Mac address.

### Why virtual MAC Address?

The Mac address allow everyone on the network to identify informations like the brand of your network card, and to follow you're connections on the network through the time. Some router will use the ip address to attribute a same ip address to the same device at each connection.

Fact is, on a public network, you prefer to have a fake Mac address in order to be annonymous. Reducing the risk of attack targeting a specific network card brand.

### Problems related to MAC Address

- if 2 devices (E.g. VMs) have the same Mac address but different IPs, half of the packets will be received by each network card. And on the computer you will see unexpected disconnection/reconnection really often.
- another related problem would be an attack by ARP poisoning, which is an attackant saying " < has <mac_attackant>" resulting in packets sent to an attackant instead of the router (man in the middle)

### Rules for creating a virtual MAC address

the `macchanger` tool on Linux allow you to change your Mac address and can be configured to take a complete random Mac address, a random Mac address belonging to a valid manufacturer, or to have a Mac address from the same manufacturer as the real Mac address, or a specific Mac address you can specify. So, except the size of the Mac address there are no specific rules.

(* The MAC and ip i chose are totally random.)

Comment: So, if I use VPN, will my MAC address be faked?

Comment: Difficult to say, I think it depends on the VPN software. In theory a VPN is a new "network adapter" and therefore use a virtual Mac address. Now, I think that different software will act differently : either taking always the same Mac address, or change everytime. - Please, if I have been helpful validate my answer (or vote up )

Comment: In fact, the MAC for IPv4 will never be realized by the web server, because it will only meaningful in its local network.   https://cyberwaters.com/does-vpn-hide-your-mac-address/

Comment: Yes, exactly, sorry if it wasn't clear.However a wifi provider can follow you're device. The Mac resolution is done by the Router/other pc on the local network.

Comment: Good point. If we use the wifi in coffee shop, the MAC is need to be randomized. Probably, this is the reason that the Windows 10 for laptop has the randomized MAC feature built in, and the PC dont.